# VIM: Conditional Key Mapping for searched pattern

Tags: vim

I want to map a key in my vimrc to comment a line by the below way:

```
<leader> N <if ; found in that line> ? 'I(*$<Esc>f)<Right>a*)<Esc>' : 'I(*$<Esc>f;a*)<Esc>'
```

But I am not able to get my intend. As I am quite new to the Vim my knowledge in it is very limited. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks:)

Comment: You are looking for a map expression (See `:h :map-expression`). However I am uncertain what you are trying to do as you are searching for `;` in the current line (`getline('.') =~ ';'`), but you use `f;` in the "false" case of your ternary expression. Therefore the `f;` can't happen if there is no `;` in the line. I think it would be helpful to describe the behavior you are trying to achieve as well as provide some example text both before and after.

Comment: There are two kinds of line in my file one ends with `;` another with `,`. I wanted to comment each of them without having two separate keys. The comment statement is also kind of unusual `(*$ <Section to be commented>*)`. I tried the  `(getline('.') =~ ';')` that is working in my case. Thanks for that. But how to use `f;` to comment the statement that I am not able to figure out.

Comment: Currently I am using the the below keystroke which is working for me
`vnoremap <expr> <leader>t (getline('.') =~ ';') ? "I(*$<Esc>f;a*)<Esc>" : "I(*$<Esc>f)<Right>a*)<Esc>" ` Also can I use it in visual mode as well where I will select multiple lines in visual mode and it will comment all of them?

Comment: I do not think that you are on the easiest track. maybe a sample with text/code/wjatever you have and the result you want would be helpful